# Binding data in two respective $scope in AngularJS, how?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to bring some data from $scope 1 to $scope 2.
Here below, I am trying to pass "project_data.title" or "$$scope.project_data.project_title" in $scope 1 to $scope.test in $scope 2.

[$scope A]

```
$scope.updateData = function(project_id){
    $http.post("../crud/projects_update.php",{
        project_id : $scope.project_data.project_id,    
        project_title : $scope.project_data.project_title // this should be passed to $scope B.
    })
```

[$scope B]

```
$http.get('../crud/customers_read.php',{

}).then(function(response){
    $scope.customer = [];
    $scope.customers = response.data;
    $scope.test = { name: $scope.project_data.project_title }; // This should come from $scope A.
});
```

I thought they are universal, but it seems it is not. How do you usually solve this kind of problem: binding the data for different $scope?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should really create an `$http` service, and only inject it into the controllers where it's used.

Comment: As of angular 1.2, you should be using [controller as](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) syntax. The Angularjs team added this syntax to solve precisely these types of issues.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice. I will look into it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scopes in Angular can reference *up* the ladder to parent scopes by default unless you isolate them. It seems likely that your two scopes, if siblings, do not inherit each others' scopes by default.

For example:

`scope A -> scope B` : scope B can reference scope A variables

`scope C <- scope A -> scope B` : scope B and scope C can reference scope A variables, but scope B cannot reference scope C variables or vice versa

You can use `$rootScope`, but that will land you in messy *scope soup* state handling as your application scales.

I would suggest that you instead place the data in a *service*.

So scope A will publish the data to the `CommonDataSvc` and then scope B can reference the data there.

This will keep your state better organized.

Another option would be to implement Redux.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! It helped me understand better. Hope this helps the others as well!